# Wordpress navigation Menus

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem where on my WordPress theme if i have a menu assigned in Appearance->Menus the styling is okay but if i do not have one assigned i loose the styling as my navigation bar styles on the ul tag and not the div tag. The custom menu's use the ul tag with the class specified but if no menu is assigned to the location it puts the styling in the div tag.

As you can see on the picture below this is what i get outputted when menu specified
[Menu Specified](http://wp-creation.com/liquid-frontend-1.PNG)

this outputs
`<div id="menu_dropdown">
                <ul id="menu-default" class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal" style="left: 14px; top: 38px; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0">`

using the following code in functions.php

`function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array( 'primary' => __( 'Header Menu' ) )
  );
}`

and the following in header.php

`<div id="menu_dropdown">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'menu'            => '', 
    'container'       => '', 
    'container_class' => '', 
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'dropdown dropdown-horizontal', 
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" style="left: 14px; top: 38px; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0">%3$s</ul>',  ) ); ?>
    </div>`

but the styling goes like this when no menu specified
[Menu Not Specified](http://wp-creation.com/liquid-frontend-2.PNG)

and outputs
`<div id="menu_dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal"><ul>
</ul>
</div></div>.`

This is not a styling issue as in my stylesheet i have all the correct classes e.g ul.dropdown etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead this:

keep blank your `items_wrap`

and try with this one:

```
<div id="menu_dropdown"> <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => '', 'menu_class' => 'dropdown dropdown-horizontal', 'menu_id' => 'menu-default' ) ); ?> </div>
```

And now play with your CSS.

Thanks.